# Checkboxes to be checked based on the file and stored in the file in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

I have 5 checkboxes, 1 button, and a text file. In my text file the values are stored like this:

> 1,0,0,0,1

When I run the program, the first and last checkboxes need to be checked and the others need to be unchecked.

If I check or uncheck any of the checkboxes then click the save button, the changed values have to be updated in text file. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var filename:String = "checkboxes.txt";
var checkboxes:Vector.<CheckBox> = new <CheckBox>[checkbox1, checkbox2, etc];

function load():void {
    // read text file
    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(filename);
    if(!file.exists)
        return;
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    var text:String = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
    fileStream.close();

    // decode text values to checkboxes
    var values:Array = text.split(",");
    for(var i:int = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        var checked:Boolean = values[i] == "1";
        checkboxes[i].selected = checked;
    }
}

function save():void {
    // encode checkboxes to text
    var values:Array = [];
    for(var i:int = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        values.push(int(checkboxes[i].selected));
    }
    var text:String = values.join(",");

    // write to file
    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(filename);
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes(text);
    fileStream.close();
}
```

Comment: i create text file in current path
but have error in run
errors:
Line 6 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: File.
Line 7 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: FileStream.
Line 6 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method File.
Line 7 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method FileStream.
Line 8 1120: Access of undefined property FileMode.
Line 29 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: File.
Line 30 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: FileStream.

Comment: In this case you should use `app-storage:` url scheme, or `File.applicationStorageDirectory`. I'll update my example.

Comment: You also need to import all the classes in use, for example `import flash.filesystem.File`

Comment: very tanx
but have error in import flash.filesystem.File
error:
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: File.
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: FileStream.

Comment: Are you using AIR like you tagged for this question? The `File` class is only available in AIR, not the Flash Player.

Comment: many tanx ... I can use this code In "Air For Android" in flash cs6?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `File` class in AIR for Android.

Comment: tanx for help
run Was this code white error in output:


[SWF] Untitled-2_Scene%201.swf - 33887 bytes after decompression
Error: Error #3003: File or directory does not exist.
 at flash.filesystem::FileStream/open()
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[Untitled_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:17]
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
 at runtime::AppRunner/run()
 at ADLAppEntry/run()
 at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
[UnloadSWF] Untitled-2_Scene%201.swf
Test Movie terminated.

Comment: You cannot `open()` a file as `FileMode.READ` if the file doesn't exist. You can check if a file exists by using `File/exists`. I'll update my example to take this into consideration.

Comment: many tanx ... this is code run very good and no error ... but in run checkbox no checked... i save Each file in Desktop and create text file in Desktop(current)...where is my problem?

Comment: Ooooh my GOD...i change "File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(filename);"  to "File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(filename);"  and it is run without problem and work Properly.

Comment: Cool, yes you can put the file wherever you want. Just make sure both `save()` and `load()` use the same file location. ;)

Comment: now just problem is in save :
SecurityError: fileWriteResource
 at flash.filesystem::FileStream/open()

Comment: now just is 1 Problem...
in read file " var file:File=File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(filename);"  is  work Properly but in write file not work...
in write file "var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(filename);"  work Properly ... and my problem is desktop directory... i need read & write file only current file.

Comment: Well, `applicationDirectory` often does not allow write, this is why you usually use `applicationStorageDirectory`.